# when re-sizing webpage, text gets smaller and creates more lines

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for my whole website, hope this helps! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Toontown Classic</title>
    <meta name='description' content='Official website of Toontown Classic.'/>
    <meta name='keywords' content='toontown, toontown online, toontown infinite, toontown'/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
</head>
    <body>
        <!--Background-->
        <div id="background">
            <img src="blue.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
        </div>
        <!--Logo-->
        <div align = "center">
            <img src = "TT_Logo.png">
        </div>
        <!--Nav Bar-->
        <div align = "center">
            <p><div style="width:900px;height:60px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-    radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;background-color:white; opacity:0.52;"></div></p>       
        </div>
        <!--Bottom Content Box-->
        <div align = "center">
            <p><div style="width:900px;height:900px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;background-color:white; opacity:0.52;"></div></p>
        </div>
        <!--Date&By-->
        <div id="DateAndBy">
            <div align = "center">
                <p>Posted by Sir Biscuit, November 5, 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="NewsPosts">
                <p>Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon!</p>
    </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
}
#background {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1; 
}
.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#DateAndBy {
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
top: -930px;
font-size: 30px; 
margin-left: 10; 
margin-right: 10; 
text-indent: 5; 
}
#NewsPosts{
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
top: -925px;
width: 45%;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 20px; 
margin-left: 10; 
margin-right: 10; 
text-indent: 5; 
}
```

Hope this code helps out, please note I am new to web developing, so please don't hate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using percentage based sizes.  Try changing your `width: 45%;` to something like `width: 600px;`

Comment: @JayBot, could you post ALL your HTML and CSS code?  I know what's wrong, but I need all of the relevant code.

Comment: That looks like 60px, but would really need to see more markup so we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you haven't given a value for your left or right margins, nor your text-indent - merely digits, which is necessary and it's likely your computer's trying to compensate by forcing a guess of either pixels, ems, or percentage.

You will have to choose which unit of measure best fits your project even though they can be converted between the three - pixels, ems, or percentages.

Since you have already specified pixels, I suggest you choose numbers of pixels to bring the text to the size you want.  I would also suggest continuing the 'auto' attribute since it would work to force your code in line with the pixels already present.

Comment: He DOES have a margin value.  `margin:0 auto` is a perfectly valid and common value for `margin`.

Comment: `margin-left:10;` is NOT a value. It needs to have `px` after the 10. Same goes to `margin-right:10;`

Comment: Without the number of [enter measurement here] desired/necessary, the stylesheet can't do anything because the code breaks.  As soon as it attempts to render your particular snippet, the site will break.  The 404 message is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the inline styling in your page and make them a class

HTML:

```
<div style="width:900px;height:900px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;background-color:white; opacity:0.52;display: inline-block;">
    <div id="NewsPosts">
            <p>Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon! Toontown Classic is coming soon!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#NewsPosts {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-indent: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#NewsPosts p {
    text-align:justify;
}
```

This should fix your issue.